# How do I increment a label value with a button press in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to increment a label by 2 when I click a button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cur = 0;

    @IBOutlet weak var money: UILabel!

    @IBAction func pressbutton(sender: UIButton) {
        cur = money.text!.toInt()!;
        self.money.text = String(cur + 2);

    }

}
```

Here is my current code but I am getting the error

> toInt() is unavaliable: Use Int() initializer

on this line

```
cur = money.text!.toInt()!;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this error by changing the offending code to the following:

```
cur = Int(money.text!)!;
```

Read more about initializers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html). An excerpt:

> Initialization is the process of preparing an instance of a class,
>   structure, or enumeration for use. This process involves setting an
>   initial value for each stored property on that instance and performing
>   any other setup or initialization that is required before the new
>   instance is ready for use.

Answer (score 13):

You shouldn't be using the content of a label to increment your label according to MVC programming. Instead, use a variable to store your `Int` and update the label by adding a property observer to the variable like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!

    var someValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            someLabel.text = "\(someValue)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someValue = 0 // didSet is called when the variable is changed, not upon initialization.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        someValue += 2
    }
}
```

Also, I would consider renaming your variable to something more descriptive than `cur`, and you may omit the semicolons as they are unnecessary.

Answer (score -3):

```
money.text = "\(Int(money.text!)! + 2)"
```